# Saving just the value from a Pandas DataFrame row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking up a certain row in my Pandas DataFrame by using the index - the row information is stored in variable `p`. As you can see `p` gives me a normal Pandas DataFrame. Now I want to save just the integer in `in_reply_to_status_id` as variable `y` but, in my code below, it gives me an object. Does anyone know if and how it would be possible to just store the integer (`1243885949697888263` in this case) as `y?`
[image]

Comment: Can you add information about the data type of `p['in_reply_to_status_id']` in the question?

Answer (score 1):

y is a series, you can try as follow to pick second (1243885949697888263) value

```
print(y.array[0])
```

Comment: Yes this did the trick thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
y = df.at[i, 'in_reply_to_status_id']
```

That way you don't have to create `p`.

If you want to do it with `p`:

```
y = p.iloc[0].at['in_reply_to_status_id']
```

Or:

```
y = p.iat[0,1]
```

Or:

```
y = p.at[i, 'in_reply_to_status_id']
```